# RecursionLimit error when Plotting a recursive function

Tags: plotting

Why am I getting the error $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

when I try to plot this `fib` Fibonacci function in Mathematica?

```
Plot[fib[n], {n, 0, 20}]
```

Where `fib` is defined as:

```
Clear[fib];
fib[0] := 1;
fib[1] := 1;
fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
```

Comment: Use this code `DiscretePlot[fib[n], {n, 0, 20}]` or `ListPlot[Table[fib[n], {n, 0, 20}]]` rather than `Plot`

Comment: Use `Plot[]` when you need to use continuous functions, like in `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Answer (score 3):

**Original**

Use this code `DiscretePlot[fib[n], {n, 0, 20}]` or `ListPlot[Table[fib[n], {n, 0, 20}]]` rather than `Plot`. `Plot` is intended for continuous-valued functions, not functions that are explicitly intended only to be defined over non-negative integers, as is the case here.

```
Clear[fib];
fib[0] := 1;
fib[1] := 1;
fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];

DiscretePlot[fib[n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
ListPlot[Table[fib[n], {n, 0, 10}]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

**Edit**

If you use recurrence relation with `RSolve` like this, you would get the general formula that is applied to `Plot` as continuous function.

```
fb = f[n] /. 
  RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[1] == f[0] == 1}, f[n], n][[1]]
```

> `1/2 (Fibonacci[n] + LucasL[n])`

```
Plot[fb, {n, 0, 10},
 Prolog -> DiscretePlot[fib[n], {n, 0, 10}][[1]]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

Comment: thanks you guys have been so helpful